# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series - How to save dataframe.apply as json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My dataframe- [image]

My code-

```
import json

df=pd.read_csv("file")

import numpy as np
def get_lengths(s):
    cols = s.index[::2]
    labels = s.index[1::2]
    l = list(np.cumsum(list(map(len, s[cols]))))
    l = list(zip([0]+l[:-1], l))
    
    return (' '.join(s[cols]), {'entities': [list(zip(l, labels))]})

TRAIN_DATA= df.apply(get_lengths, axis=1)
with open('G:/Downloads/output5.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(TRAIN_DATA)
```

I am getting this error - `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series`
My output is something like this -

```
('House 263 dhaka mirpur',
 {'entities': [[((0, 9), 'label1'),
    ((9, 14), 'label2'),
    ((14, 20), 'label3')]]})
```

How should I save this as json?

Answer (score 1):

After applying the function, converted to json file using [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and specifying the file path.

Working code looks like this:

```
data_fr= df.apply(get_lengths, axis=1)
data_fr.to_json("file_path")
```